# Spark Streaming+Elasticsearch: Cannot resolve symbol saveToEs

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to save `RDD[(Object,Object)] messages` into ElasticSearch using `saveToEs`. In the code below I iterate over `DStream[String] transformed` and for each `RDD[String] rdd` I create `RDD[(Object,Object)]` using `prepare`. The problem is that `saveToEs` is marked in red though I added the artifact `elasticsearch-hadoop` (version 2.3.2) into `pom.xml`:

```
transformed.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  if (!rdd.isEmpty) {
    val messages = rdd.map(prepare)
    messages.saveToEs(ec.getResource().toString)
  }
})

private def prepare(message:String):(Object,Object) = {

   val m = JSON.parseFull(message) match {
      case Some(map) => map.asInstanceOf[Map[String,String]]
      case None => Map.empty[String,String]
   }

   val kw = NullWritable.get

   val vw = new MapWritable
   for ((k, v) <- m) vw.put(new Text(k), new Text(v))

   (kw, vw)       
}
```

Comment: What IDE do you use?

Comment: @MirMasej: IntellijIDEA 2016.1.1. The strange thing is that `saveToEs` works for SparkContext, but it is highlighted in red if I want to use StreamingContext.

Comment: First, make sure that the code compiles from the command line: `mvn compile`. If it does, it should be a question of refreshing it in the IDE.

Comment: @MirMasej: It does not compile saying that `error: value saveToEs is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Object, Object)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import proper packages for using saveToES method which is defined in `org.elasticsearch.spark`

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-spark_2.10 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Source:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html#spark-write-scala